# UITableViewCell Leak when deleting and saving the cell

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I noticed one of my custom UITableViewCell is leaking. It is not getting released on performing edit, remove bottom cell and tap on Save. This is my top cell in the table (I call it add cell). Once my table view is in edit mode, Add cell is shown up with all the other cells shown underneath with delete mode on. Now, after performing the delete operation and saving the data, Add Cell still hang around even if dealloc on my table view gets called.

I am attaching my code and instrument screenshot (I've removed first line (Malloc call) from the screenshot. To me, it appears to be something wrong in iOS internal handling. Please advise.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *aCell = nil;
    NSString *aCellType;

    if (iIndexPath.row == 0 && self.inEditMode) {
        aCellType = kMyAddCell;
        aCell = (MyAddCell *)[iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:aCellType];

        if (!aCell) {
            aCell = [[MyAddCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:aCellType];
        }

        aCell.isGroupedView = YES;
        aCell.delegate = self;
        aCell.textLabel.text = @“Add More";
        self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    } else {
        aCellType = kMyDefaultCell;
        aCell = (MyTableViewCell *)[iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:aCellType];

        if (!aCell) {
            aCell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:aCellType];
        }

        NSInteger anIndex = iIndexPath.row;

        if (self.inEditMode) {
            anIndex = anIndex - 1;
        }

        aCell.textLabel.text = @“Name";
        aCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    return aCell;
}


- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    return (iIndexPath.row == 0 && self.inEditMode) ? UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone : UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)iEditingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    if (iEditingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [self setSaveModeNavigationBar];
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.enabledUsers removeObjectAtIndex:(self.inEditMode) ? iIndexPath.row - 1 : iIndexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[iIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}


- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)iEditing animated:(BOOL)iAnimated {
    [super setEditing:iEditing animated:iAnimated];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];

    self.headerViewLabel.text = @“Edit Me";

    UIBarButtonItem *aDoneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@“Done"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                   target:self
                                                                   action:@selector(cancelEditing)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:aDoneButton];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.inEditMode = YES;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Code that gets called once I tap on Save button:

```
    self.requestHandler = [[MyRequestHandler alloc] initWithEndPoint:myEndPoint body:aPostBody successHandler:^(NSDictionary *iResponse) {
        [aBlockSelf addNoDataOverlay];
    } andErrorHandler:^(NSString *iMessage, NSString *iKey, NSInteger iErrorCode, BOOL iIsNetworkError) {
        [aBlockSelf addNoDataOverlay];
    }];

[self.requestHandler executeRequest];
```

**Instrument Allocation Stack:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it turned out to be a known issue being tracked in [this thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/630695#630695). Tried the same steps in iPhone 5S (iOS 8) and issue has been resolved there.